# Pointing two sets of private nameservers to one pair of IPs

Tags: dns, bind, named, nameservers

I'm in the middle of migrating servers from one provider to another due to reliability issues.

Anyway, I've had the domain jeffkee.com for a while, so

```
ns1.jeffkee.com -> xxx.xxx.xxx.x (whatever the previous IP is.. is irrelevant)
ns2.jeffkee.com -> xxx.xxx.xxx.x (whatever the previous IP is.. is irrelevant)
```

They both connect to server **I** (we'll call it **I** for Inmotion hosting). I have a few dozen websites with domains set up to those nameservers.

While migrating, I set up another domain, sonika.ca so I can migrate in stages to ensure server compliance etc. for all my PHP apps. So now I have

```
ns1.sonika.ca -> 64.207.177.33
ns2.sonika.ca -> 64.207.177.100
```

pointing towards the new server at **M** (we'll call it **M** for media temple), to the two IP addresses on the server M.

So my question here is.. if I migrate all the files & database etc. and set them up on the new server **M**, and then simply update my domain jeffkee.com at Netfirms (domain registrar) so that the ns1.jeffkee.com/ns2.jeffkee.com points towards the new IPs on server M, will this work? Or does this cause some weird DNS problem I am not aware of?

Essentially, this is the final result I'm proposing:

```
ns1.sonika.ca & ns1.jeffkee.com -> 64.207.177.33
ns2.sonika.ca & ns2.jeffkee.com -> 64.207.177.100
```

This way I don't have to walk dozens of people through how to update their name servers for their domains one by one.. which can be a tedious task.

Google searches returned some ambiguous results, most of them discussing whether the ns1 & ns2 should both have same IP or different IP etc. so I've turned here for help.

Answer (score 1):

You will possibly run into some issues with glue records as the registrar will have a different IP address for the nameserver than you have migrated to, so anyone querying the hierarchy could potentially get the old IP address.

My advice would be to migrate the data and ensure that all of the DNS on the new provider is correctly configured. Then update the zone records on the old provider to point at the resources on the new hosting provider. Then you can gradually go through each zone and update the registrar to point at the new provider. The once everything is migrated ditch the old provider.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But my original question of being able to point multiple private nameservers to the same IPs - is that going to be OK?

Comment: Yeah it should be fine as a temporary measure, the nameserver will respond to the client with the correct response. It's only if you start tracing DNS queries with dig (using +trace) that you may run into issues as the hierarchy will say that a different set of nameservers are hosting the domain (even though they are actually the same nameservers just with a different name). For neatness and completeness the whole chain should match.